# Integration with Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: users

My client want to integrate [Azure Active Directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) with Drupal.  Is this possible?  What is the best starting point for this process?

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you need from integration?  Just authentication?  Other user profile fields?

Comment: Actually User data needs to be saved in Azure Active Directory so while user registration, a user account need to created in active directory and store the user data there. user login must authenticate password in active directory. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Yes, It is possible in drupal by custom module.